# Crystal Report - This field can't be summarized

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a formula  `ABC`

```
sum({Table1.col1},{Table2.FieldName})
```

My report is grouped by `Table2.FieldName`.
Then then want to add the value of `ABC` to another column's value.

My formula :

```
sum({@ABC},{Table2.Col1})
```

Here, I am getting this error that `@ABC` cant be summarized.

Is their any workaround to add these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal can't total other totals.

If you explain the situation in more details, there may be another way to accumulate the desired total.

Alternatively, Ken Hamady maintains a list of 3rd-party Crystal Reports UFLs (User Function Libraries) [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl). At least one of them allows you to do totals of totals by providing functions that allow Crystal formulas to accumulate and retrieve total values in memory.